# setInterval not repeating a word change

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I'm getting an understanding of JavaScript and want to make a non-interactive dictionary project. I write a word as a paragraph and I change the word to the definition using DOM as a function. When I use `setInterval` to run the function it doesn't repeat. Why?

```js
'use strict';
//below is the function for the even
$(document).ready(function(){
//

function salutation(){
    document.getElementById("Salutation").textContent ="hello";


}
setInterval(salutation, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>YOUR TITLE HERE</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="jquery.css">
    <script src="jquery.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="handler.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
   <h1>hello welcome to our dictionary</h1>

    <p>Come see what words we have to offer</p>
    <br>
    <p id = Salutation >1.Saluation</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the code just won't repeat causing the text to continuously change between the word and definition. Why?

Comment: Your code is missing a `});` and `setInterval` should be inside the `ready()` handler.  As for contually changing between word and definition, your code always sets it to `"hello"`, so you'll need to specifically code it to switch on alternating seconds using a conditional.

Comment: i did have it was just really far under my code but how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding the nature of `setTimeout`. All it does is run the first parameter function by an interval specified by the second parameter. Since your function always does the exact same thing, namely, set the `textContent` attribute of the `Salutation` element to `"hello"`, it appears to be doing nothing. There is no such default alternating behavior; you have to add that logic using a conditional of some sort. For example:

```js
function salutation(elem) {
  elem.innerText = elem.innerText === "hello" ? "world" : "hello";
}

setInterval(salutation, 1000, document.getElementById("salutation"));
```

```html
<h1>hello welcome to our dictionary</h1>
<p>Come see what words we have to offer</p>
<br>
<p id="salutation">1.Saluation</p>
```

Note that I've removed the `ready` handler and added quotes and spaces around your `id` attribute and lowercased it. These are style conventions and will matter in some situations but weren't the problem in this case, assuming your `setTimeout` function was in the same scope as your `salutation` function (you were missing a closing brace and parenthesis which made it unclear).

Lastly, I've added the `elem` as the third parameter to the `setTimeout` call for scoping purposes and avoiding extra DOM calls, but this isn't strictly necessary either.